# About vmarg for Lotus notes

Tags: lotus-notes

In order to make my notes run faster, I searched both on Google and w3 and found there is a "jvm.properties" file which contains the JVM arguments for notes incl. Xmx and Xms. I tuned them and it works fine.

But my further questions are

- Is it possible to apply other JVM tuning options to the file? e.g.
  XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC or XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled.
- Is it possible to make notes run with other JVM like JRE 7? Is "jvm.library.path" for this purpose?
- Is there a full list of the description of each vmarg?
- Is it possible to monitor notes with jconsole?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no to all of these. Th JVM for notes client or domino server cannot be changed, and the JVM args are strictly controlled through the use of notes.ini parameters.